# Set rotation and position of bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview, android-canvas

I would like to know how i both can change the position of a bitmap and at the same time rotate it. Im drawing at a canvas.

Im currently using this line of code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, posX, posY, paint);
```

and I think using a matrix for rotation is the best option?
The problem is that the line of code, posted above, doesn't take a matrix but a position.

There is also a similar line of code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

This one takes a matrix but not a position.

How should I do this?

Comment: What technology/language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.SetRotate(90,pivotX,pivotY);
matrix.PostTranslate(positionX,positionY);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix , null);
```

In words - set the position **after** rotating.

Answer (score 0):

Take the position into a matrix as posMatrix and multiply it with rotation matrix.
Then pass the resultant matrix as the parameter.

Edit ---

```
Matrix myTransformedMatrix = new Matrix();
myTransformedMatrix.setRotate(<rotation in dergrees>);
myTransformedMatrix.setTranslate(<translation in points>);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, myTransformedMatrix, paint);
```

for more info on matrix class go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Comment: Sorry, could you give me a piece of code? , as im not that good at this yet :)

Comment: why can't I both set position and rotate? It ignores my rotation? 



                        matrix.setRotate(90);
   matrix.setTranslate(pos_X, 15);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);

Comment: try using matrix.postRotate(90);